# webpack production of angular2 can't navigate with URL

Tags: angular, deployment, webpack, angular2-routing

I have an angular2 application that uses angular2 route, the dev and prod version of the webpack configuration are as described in this [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html).

When I use the dev option, running `npm start`, everything works fine and the navigation either with links on site or with full URL's like `http://localhost:3000/dashboard`.
But when I use the prod option, running `npm run build` and deploying the dist-folder output to my iis I can no longer use the URL's to navigate, and I must first go to  `http:/MyIp:3000/` and from there I can only navigate with the links on site. Any attempt to navigate with the URL leads to a 404 error.

In addition in prod mode when ever I refresh the page I get back a 404 error.

Has anyone encounter this errors? and do anyone has an idea on how to solve them?

***UPDATE***

Adding my code for webpack.common.js and for webpack.prod.js maybe someone will spot an error I overlooked...

*My webpack.common.js*

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/app/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

*My webpack.prod.js*

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },
  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're using angular-cli and I couldn't even get the dev build to work (in regards to your problem). Navigating in the app by clicking links was fine but an F5 or hitting a deep link directly didn't work. We solved it with the following URL Rewrite rule in IIS (create a web.config if you don't have one already and add it to the root folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite> 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm not sure whether it's recommended or not to use in prod but this is hosted internally and it works for now.

Comment: Cool, please mark it as the answer so it's easy for others to find, cheers.